# Saving file paths to JSON as objects in Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, list

I have a file that looks like this:

```
[["/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/data/world_building_budget.txt", []], ["/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/data/data3/world_elements.png", []], ["/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/data/data3/data4/world.bmp", []], ["/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/data/data2/world_files.pdf", []], ["/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/data/world_saving_budget.jpg", []], ["/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/a.txt", []], ["/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/.gitignore", []], ["/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_virtualenv.pth", []], ["/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/six-1.16.0.dist-info/LICENSE", []], ["/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/six-1.16.0.dist-info/WHEEL", []], ["/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/six-1.16.0.dist-info/RECORD", []], ["/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/six-1.16.0.dist-info/INSTALLER", []], ["/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/six-1.16.0.dist-info/top_level.txt", []], ["/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/six-1.16.0.dist-info/METADATA", []], ["/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytz/tzfile.py", []], ["/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytz/__pycache__/tzfile.cpython-39.pyc", []], ["/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytz/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-39.pyc", []], ["/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytz/__pycache__/tzinfo.cpython-39.pyc", []], ["/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytz/__pycache__/lazy.cpython-39.pyc", []], ["/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytz/__pycache__/reference.cpython-39.pyc", []], ["/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytz/__pycache__/exceptions.cpython-39.pyc", []], ["/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytz/zoneinfo/CET", []], ["/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytz/zoneinfo/Israel", []], 
...
```

I am populating the file with this for loop:

```
import json

data_list = [...]

data_list[:] = [[i, []] for i in data_list]

with open('content-log.json', 'a+') as json_file:
    json.dump(data_list, json_file)
```

Here is what I am trying to do.

For every path, I want to have a corresponding list. This list will have tags. These tags could be added and removed at will. For example. This path could look like this:

```
"/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/data/world_building_budget.txt", []
```

Or it could look like this:

```
"/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/data/world_building_budget.txt", [tag1, tag2, tag3]
```

I want to be able to find a path and its corresponding tags at will. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: What does it mean to "find a path"?

Comment: What problem are you having here?

Comment: Assuming each path is unique, I think a dictionary is a much better choice.

Comment: @JohnGordon I've been trying to implement this with a dictionary but couldn't. CAn you show me a demo?

Comment: Yes, each path is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a json file:

```
data = {
    "/some/path": ["tag1", "tag2"],
    "/other/path": [],
    "/different/path": ["tag3", "tag4", "tag5"]
}

with open('content-log.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Reading from the json file:

```
with open('content-log.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Comment: Now, if you add the 'w` parameter to add value to a key (which is an empty list), you get this error: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
`